# Where to find open-source widgets for Qt library?

Tags: c++, qt, open-source

I have found quite good stuff [here](http://qt-apps.org/). If you know other sites that have some good code for Qt library (some additional codes, good examples, except the Qt standard examples, of course), please share with us.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Just in general something that may Qt develper like to have in his hands. Something valuable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also please look at [Qt Solutions](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4)

Answer (score 2):

For plotting and technical purpose, there are [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) and [QtiPlot](http://soft.proindependent.com/qtiplot.html). There may be others, but often a self-made widget is faster, smaller, and better than what someone could find on the net (except qwt and qtiplot of course).

If you're looking to extend Qt a bit more, look into [KDE](http://kde.org/). It is also (experimentally) [available on Windows](http://windows.kde.org/). It adds quite a bit of functionality, but also a lot of dependencies.